# Non-generic method call in Generic class showing "type not valid"

Tags: c#, generics

C# 7

I am new to Generics. How do I fix this?

On objO = SetPatient(P), I get:

> P is a type which is not valid in the given context.

How do I fix this?

TIA

```
public interface IOrderMaker
{
    void SetPatient(IService p);
}

public class OrderMaker<O, P, T>
    where O : class, IOrderMaker
    where T : class, O, new()
    where P : IService
{
    public static O CreateInstance()
    {
        O objO;

        objO = new T();

        objO.SetPatient(P);

        return objO;
    }
}
```

Comment: `P` in this context is a generic argument type not a variable.

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). as it is unclear what it is you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetPatient` expects an *instantiated* class that implements an *interface*

```
void SetPatient(IService p);
```

however, you are giving it a generic parameter from your generic class `OrderMaker`

```
objO.SetPatient(P);
```

`P` at this point is just a bit of metadata attached to a class. Even if you could pass it to `SetPatient` there is nothing it can do with it apart from know the type. In that case your might as well make it generic as well

Answer (score 2):

`P` in this context is a generic argument type and not a variable.

You would need to pass an actual variable, not a type

```
public class OrderMaker<O, P, T>
    where O : class, IOrderMaker
    where T : class, O, new()
    where P : IService
{
    public static O CreateInstance(P p) { //<--
        O objO = new T();

        objO.SetPatient(p); //<---

        return objO;
    }
}
```

Other than that, this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as it is unclear what it is you are ultimately trying to do.